# Urn problem with n individuals and x balls who try to draw x times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to determine a certain probability in the following scenario:
I have an urn with x different balls and N individuals. We can assume that the individuals draw their balls one after the other. Each individual can draw x-balls without replacement but each of the x-draws is only picked with probability 1/2 and otherwise that ball is put back. (Therefore on average an individual draws x*1/2 balls and only the very lucky ones draw all balls). Before the next individual starts drawing, all balls are put back into the urn. Now I would like to know the probability for a random individual, that his or her draw is unique. The draw is unique when the combination of balls and their number is different to the draw of everybody else. (The order of the combination does not matter.) The number of possibe combinations is therefore 2^x.

E.g: Lets assume that we have x=3 Balls and that the different balls are enumerates by 0,1,2 and that we have 4 individuals:
The first individual could have drawn balls: 1, 2
The second individual could have drawn balls: 1, 2, 3
The third individual could have drawn balls: 2
The fourth individual could have drawn balls: 1, 2
In this case the draw of the second and third individual is unique.

Comment: What do you mean by "combination of balls and their number"?  What does it mean for a draw to be successful?

Comment: Does my example make it more clear?

Comment: Successful means that a ball is really picked.

Comment: Not really.  Does "success" have anything to do with the number on the ball?  Is "success" defined the same way for each person?  Can I say that each person draws a ball, and then flips a fair coin, and if the coin comes up heads, he is successful and gets to keep the ball, and otherwise he puts it back?  Does he keep drawing after a failure?

Comment: "Can I say that each person draws a ball, and then flips a fair coin, and if the coin comes up heads, he is successful and gets to keep the ball, and otherwise he puts it back?" Exactly

Comment: "Does he keep drawing after a failure?" Yes

Comment: You should edit your question to include all these clarifications.

Comment: otherwise it is understandable now?

Comment: Yes, I understand it, but it seems like simulation is the best approach.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question. Please let me know if there are further problems. First, I would like to think about an analytical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier than I thought at first glance.

The probability that an individual successfully draws exactly $k$ balls is $\binom{x}{k}2^{-x}$, the probability of getting $k$ heads in $x$ tosses of a fair coin.  Each of the $\binom{x}{k}$ $k$-ball combinations is equally likely, so the probability of drawing any given combination is $2^{-x}$.

Thus the probability that a given individual's draw is unique is simply the probability that everyone else draws something else, and since the events are independent, this is $$(1-2^{-x})^{N-1}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks! I have thought about my problem too complicated.